# Snowflake query result processing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone please help to understand from which layer in snowflake data is being fetched in this below plan? I understand snowflake uses either of 3 (besides results from metadata for queries like select count(*)) - result cache, warehouse cache or disk IO. In the below plan - its not from result cache ( as for the plan would say 'query result reuse'), its not showing any remote disk I/O and also the cache usage is 0%.
So its not very clear how data is being processed here. Any thoughts or pointers will be helpful.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The pictures are too small and unreadable. Please try transcribing some text. Can you add a query too?

Comment: You can use any query. Suspend the warehouse and then rerun same with slight change so results are NOT fetched from cache as suspending a warehouse is supposed to clear cache. But I am not getting consistent results or the way snowflake reports in plan is not very accurate. Sample query: select col1 from test_chr1 where 1=1; --- Next run change it to select col1 from test_chr1 where 2=2; -- to avoid fetching from result cache (if not disabled). I will try and repost image too.

Comment: To answer your question, for that particular query, it was picked up from the Storage layer where the data is stored. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes most likely. I am trying to understand why its not showing same in the plan as it depicts clearly when I/O is used (i.e. fetched from storage). The same is reported as "Remote Disk I/O" under profile overview section of the plan but the same is missing from this plan output.

Comment: @Pankaj What is the output of: `SELECT * FROM QUERY_HISTORY WHERE QUERY_ID=?`

Comment: I will post this in original question.

Answer (score 1):

The picture says that 0.44MB were scanned.

The picture says that 0% of those 0.44MB came from the local cache.

Hence 0.44MB were read from the main storage layer.

Comment: Please check bytes_spilled_to_local_storage

Comment: Oh, thanks for now adding more context to the question so we can give you a better answer. `bytes_spilled_to_local_storage` doesn't mean bytes read or written, but something that happens on complex queries. You still haven't shared your query, so we can't talk about that. In the meantime, check https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Performance-impact-from-local-and-remote-disk-spilling to understand `bytes_spilled_to_local_storage`.

Comment: select col2 from test_chr1_1 where 20=20;

create or replace temporary table test_chr1_1 (col1 char(100), col2 varchar2(100000));

Comment: That's a simple query. It won't spill bytes.

Comment: "spilling bytes" is "running out of ram and swapping to disk", it happens when you are doing crazy large joins and aggregations across too much data to hold in the instance size you have.

Answer (score 1):

The data is read from the storage layer. I will assume AWS, thus from the S3 there you table is stored. There are three primary reasons for a remote read:

- It is the first time this warehouse has used this data. This is the same thing that happens if you stop/start the warehouse.
- The data has changed (which can be anything from 0% - 100% change of partitions), given in your example there is only one partition, any insertion happening in the back ground will cause 100% cache invalidation.
- The data was flushed from the local caches by more active data, if you read this table once every 30 minutes, but between then read GB of other tables, like all caches low usage data gets dropped.

The result cache can be used, but it also can be turned off for a session, but then local disk cache still happens. And you `WHERE 20 = 20` in theory might cache bust the result cache, but as it's a meaningless statement it might not. But given your results it seems, at this point of time it's enough to trick the result cache. Which implies if you want to not avoid the result cache, stop changing the number, and it you want to avoid, this seems to work.

I see you have highlighted the two spilling options, those are when working state data is too large for memory, and too large for local disk so are sent to remote (s3). The former is a sign your warehouse is undersized, and both are a hint that something in your query is rather bloated. Now maybe that is what you want/needed, but it slows things down very much. Now to know if there is perhaps "another way" if in the profile plan there is some step that goes `100M rows -> 100GB rows -> 42 rows` this implies a giant mess was made, and then some filter smashed the heck out of nearly all of it, which implies the work could be done different, to avoid that large explosion/filtering.